# Come mai dal latino "ceresa" si è giunti all'italiano "ciliegia"?

Tags: etymology

Ecco una domanda stagionale :-)

La parola latina per ciliegia è *ceresa, -ae*, a sua volta proveniente dal greco *kerasa*. In molti dialetti italiani il termine mantiene le consonanti iniziali, ma in italiano (a parte la ĕ breve che come succede in generale si è trasformata in i) ci sono state ben due trasformazioni consonantiche: -r- in -l-  e -s- in -g-. Qualcuno ha idea di come siano potute esserci queste modifiche, magari con qualche altro esempio etimologico?

Comment: In molti dialetti la parola si è conservata molto simile al latino: http://www.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail_new.lasso?id=218 sono curioso anche io di sapere l'etimologia della parola italiana attuale

Comment: Stavo aggiungendo un commento simile. In sardo (e nella maggior parte dei suoi dialetti) si chiamano "Criaxi" (si legge più o meno "Criasgi"). Può essere interessante perché comincia a comparire il suono della G come un piccolo seme :) (dalla lista che ho visto la pronuncia non si evince facilmente).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some Vulgar Latin variants, there was a regular sound change of intervocalic *-si-* > *-dʒ-* (the Latin word was actually *ceresia* with an *i*). Other examples are *Lutetia Parisiorum* 'Paris' > *Parigi* and *Dionysius* > *Dionigi*. It was probably part of the other palatalization processes in Late Latin, which are also responsible for the change of the initial *k-* > *tʃ-*. Unfortunately I couldn't find any literature which specifically describes this particular sound change.

As for *-r-* > *-l-*, it's not unheard of that these two sounds get interchanged sporadically, but I don't know any other examples in Italian. In any case, it was probably not a regular sound change.

Comment: Are you sure the Latin word was *ceresia*? Before the reform proposed by Bruno Migliorini, the plural form of "ciliegia" was "ciliege" **without** an I (see the posthumous book by Oriana Fallaci), and the original rule for pluralization involved looking at the Latin origin of the word.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cherry) has Vulgar Latin _*ceresia_. Lindsay's [The Latin Language](https://archive.org/stream/latinlanguagehis00linduoft#page/18/mode/2up) Ch. II. § 5 lists _ceresio_ as well as _ceresium_ and _cerasium_, but reconstructs an original form _*ceresus_, which is plausible, as it's a loan from Gk. _κερασός_. Maybe this was the justification?

Comment: it may be. Actually I just checked on De Mauro dictionary, which gives as etymology "lat. *cerĕsĕa(m), derived from cerasus "ciliegio, ciliegia", from gr. kérasos."

Comment: Spanish Catalina comes to my mind as an example of r > l

Comment: An example of r → l: _arbor_ → _albero_

Answer (score 3):

Dal lat. parl. *cerĕsea(m)*, da *cĕrasus* ‘ciliegio’, dal gr. *κέρᾰσος* (kérasos), forse dalla radice *kar=kra* esser duro (a cagione della durezza del legno o del nocciolo (cfr. [ciriegio e ciliegio](http://www.etimo.it/?term=ciriegio))

Da *ceresea* si ha *ciriegia* tramite:

- chiusura della *ĕ* protonica in *i* (cfr. Rohlfs)
- dittongazione di *ĕ* in *ie* in sillaba aperta accentata (cfr. pĕdem → piede, pĕtra → pietra)
- chiusura della *ĕ* postonica in *i* in sillaba non finale [cfr. Rohlfs]
- nesso *sibilante + jod*, che in questo caso ha prodotto una sibilante palatale sonora tenue *-ʒ-* e poi *-dʒ-* (cfr. segūsiŭ(m) > [se'guʒo]> [se'gudʒo] segugio) [si veda ad es. Rohlfs per sonorizzazione delle consonanti intervocaliche].

Dunque: da *ceresea* si ha *ciriegia*, e poi, in epoca relativamente recente, fra il Cinque e il Secento, ciriegia si trasforma in ciliegia.

Il **Rohlfs** pensa che *ciliegia*, con *-l-* invece di *-r-*, sia di provenienza francese. Un'altra spiegazione era stata offerta dallo **Jud**: supponendo che la voce fiorentina sia presa a prestito dall'ant. ligure *ceresa*, la *-l-* potrebbe essere dovuta al desiderio d'evitare quello che veniva sentito come un difetto dei Liguri, ossia l'uso di *r* intervocalica per *l*.

Secondo **Castellani**:

> Fra il Cinque e il Secento, *ciriegia* si trasforma in *ciliegia*. Perché questo cambiamento? Perché, direi, il dittongo *iè* dopo *r* si pronuncia male (la presenza di *r* costringe a dar pieno valore vocalico alla prima componente: *ciri-egia*). In un periodo in cui *brieve* si riduce a *breve*, *criepa* a *crepa*, ecc., per *ciriegia* si sceglie un'altra possibilità (che non esiste nel caso di *ie* preceduto da *cons. + r*): si conserva il dittongo, e si sostituisce *l* a *r*. La nuova forma, evidentemente, non può essere nata nella Toscana meridionale o in Lucchesia (dove s'è sempre usato il tipo CERASEA), né nella Toscana orientale (dove si ha *siregia* o *ciregia*). E non ci sarà da pensare nemmeno a Pisa (il Malagòli, Voc. pis., segnala un'attestazione di *ceragia* ancora nel sec. XVII). Rimane Firenze col suo distretto, e la zona di Prato-Pistoia. In ogni modo, dal Secento in poi la forma *ciliegia* è caratteristicamente fiorentina; e come tale è stata accolta nella lingua letteraria.
> (**A. Castellani**)

**Autocorrezione di Arrigo Castellani** (Saggi di linguistica e filologia italiana e romanza, Roma, Salerno Editrice, 1980, tomo II, pp. 14-15):

> Va corretta la frase della mia nota del 1960 in cui si dice che «la presenza di r costringe a dar pieno valore vocalico alla prima componente del dittongo *iè*». Non c’è nessuna tendenza, nel fiorentino contemporaneo, a dar carattere vocalico alla *i* di «Via dell’Ariento». Tale tendenza può esserci stata quattro secoli fa: ma la cosa ha importanza secondaria. Quel che conta, è che la sequenza *voc. + r + iè* apparisse anomala. Sarà un caso che le due sole voci popolari che la contenevano, *ariento* e *ciriegia*, siano state sostituite da voci diverse? Non è lecito collegare questa sostituzione coll’essere venuta a mancare, in una serie di parole ben altrimenti consistente, la sequenza *cons. + r + iè*?
>
> Tornando oggi sul problema, penso si debba tener conto dell’ipotesi che ciliegia sia una forma fanciullesca. La *r* è l’ultima consonante che i bambini, o per lo meno molti bambini, imparino ad articolar bene. Uno dei suoni più vicini è *l*; e *l* è suggerita dall’articolo: *le ciriegie > le ciliegie*. Il tipo con *-l-* sarebbe potuto rimanere sotto il limitare della «lingua»: s’è imposto in un momento particolarmente favorevole, quando cioè la vecchia norma riguardante *cons. + r + iè* cedeva alla nuova (con riflessi su *voc. + r + iè*).
>
> È ovviamente da escludersi che il ligure antico *ceresa* o il francese *cerise* (ci si chiede perché *cerise*, visto che il rotacismo non esiste in francese come fenomeno caratterizzante) abbiano fornito al fiorentino, nel secolo XVI, «a model for “hyper-Tuscanism”».

Comment: Complimenti per l'approfondimento di questa risposta!