# Sull'uso del termine "varco"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

***[Varco:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/varco/)*** : (Treccani)

> - ***Valico montano***: i varchi delle Alpi, degli Appennini. ***Con questo significato è raro; comune  invece con il significato più generico di passaggio, luogo o apertura per dove si passa***.

Espressioni molto comuni:

- ***aprirsi un varco***: riuscire a trovare uno spazio per passare: aprirsi un v. nella fitta foresta, nei reticolati, tra la folla.
- ***aspettare o cogliere  (qualcuno) al varco***: 
  *appostarsi per sorprenderlo al passaggio di un luogo*; ***fig.*** *prenderlo alla sprovvista, aspettarlo alla prova, attendere l'occasione propizia per rivalersi su di lui*.

Perché l'uso di questo termine è così diffuso in senso figurato nel linguaggio comune? È legato a storie o specifici eventi del passato?

Comment: Non capisco bene la domanda. Capirei di più se la domanda fosse sull'espressione _varco non attivo_ che si legge sui display dei varchi della ZTL di Roma quando sono aperti a tutti...

Comment: @WalterTross - *varco non attivo* è in effetti un altro interessante uso del termine diverso dal suo originario. È proprio questa la mia domanda, perché *varco* (valico montano) è un termine così comune in senso figurato?

Comment: Non ho il tempo per una risposta completa, ma il termine da cui derivano _varco_, ma anche _divaricare_, _prevaricare_, _valicare_, _valico_ e altri è il latino _vārus_, "(con le gambe) storte in fuori", _varo_ (tuttora usato in ortopedia). Peraltro, nel caso di _valico_, si tratta di un esempio di trasformazione R⇒L di cui si parla in [questa domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/come-mai-dal-latino-ceresa-si-%C3%A8-giunti-allitaliano-ciliegia/2010)

Comment: Varco ha significato di passaggio, non capisco il problema dell'uso figurato...

Comment: aggiungerei che si chiamano valichi anche i passaggi stradali di confine.

Answer (score 3):

Il mio dizionario dà:

> 1 Passaggio, di solito angusto e superabile a fatica: uno stretto v.
>   fra le rocce; aprirsi un v. tra la folla; fig. , il passaggio dalla
>   vita alla morte. 2 Come nome di azione, attraversamento, valico.

Entrambi i casi che menzioni sono sì espressioni idiomatiche, ma usano varco nel suo significato. Ciò che è figurato è l'intero detto (non aspetti veramente qualcuno ad un varco, ma all'interno di questa analogia "varco" è usato nel suo senso originario). Il fatto, poi, che non sia una parola molto comune ha fatto sì che si senta soprattutto in relazione a queste espressioni. Come Walter Tross scrive nei commenti, "varco" riferito ad un accesso della ZTL è un uso legittimo e non figurato (al di là della stranezza di "varco non attivo").

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Bzazz!

Comment: @Bzazz -        *"Il fatto, poi, che non sia una parola molto comune ha fatto sì che si senta soprattutto in relazione a queste espressioni."*  Questo è il punto della mia domanda, ossia che non sia un termine  molto comune ma che nonostante questo sia entrato nel linguaggio comune attraverso modi  di dire o altre espressioni come il varco ZTL. Non si poteva più comunemente chiamate "passaggio ZTL" ad esempio? La mia impressione è che il termine evochi e faccia riferimento ad espressioni comuni in passato, legate alla guerra forse?